# Conditional svn checkout in polling Jenkins job

Tags: svn, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to prevent an svn checkout on an svn-polling Jenkins job depending on a condition. Pre-steps are executed after the checkout and this job is triggered through svn polling. Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

There is a plugin that allows to execute a step before SVN checkout
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/pre-scm-buildstep
<strike>However, it does not prevent the job from continuing even if those pre-scm steps fail.</strike> Latest versions allow to fail the build if this pre-build step fails.

One thing I can think of is to setup 2 jobs. One job's task is solely to poll SVN, and if conditions are met, then trigger a build using the second job. The second job can even use "custom workspace" option and use the workspace of the first job to prevent additional checkouts

Comment: Thank you very much! From what you're explaining, a c/o is unavoidable if I want to poll SVN. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, unless you write your own polling mechanism. You can use this plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ScriptTrigger+Plugin to execute a custom shell script, and if that script succeeds, then the build starts, else it won't. In that shell script, you can write your own polling with whatever conditions you may want

Comment: The ability to fail the build if pre-scm fails has been added :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is still relevant, but I might have found a workaround for this problem.Let say that you have an SVN repo with a root called 'svn_root' and under it you have you trunk folder, your tag folder, your branch folder, etc.
You only want Jenkins to poll your 'svn_root' without having to checkout the content of your trunk/tags/branch.To do so, in your job configuration, in the subversion part, put in your 'repository url' box your high level url (eg: svn://ip/svn_root) and in the 'repository depth' dropdown choose 'immediates'.When the job will start, jenkins will only check the high level folder (svn_root) and will trigger only if there was a change in it.By example, if there was a commit in the trunk, the trunk entry of the high level folder will change, and the job will be triggered.
That completely did the trick for me.
Hope I helped
Good luck